# Elastic Search analyzer and synonym not working

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my mapping and properties

```
POST hr-profile/employee-type
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_metaphone": {
          "replace": "false",
          "type": "phonetic",
          "encoder": "metaphone"
        },
        "synonym": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms_path": "analysis/names.txt"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_metaphone"
          ],
          "char_filter": [
            "my_pattern"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        },
        "synonym": {
          "filter": [
            "synonym"
          ],
          "char_filter": [
            "my_pattern"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_pattern": {
          "pattern": "\\.|\\;|\\,",
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "replacement": " "
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "companyid": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "emailaddress": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "employeeid": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "firstname": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "lastname": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "phonenumber": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "profileid": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have data in the index but getting error
[match] analyzer [synonym] not found"

Help needed pls.

Comment: i'm using elasticsearch 7.4.1 and kibana 7.2.0.

Comment: can you provide your search query which is throwing error?